# ASP Table overlap to next column

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I'm having trouble with the layout of my table. As you can see in the screenshot there is a grid view within a gridview. The example you see has 3 grid views the main one and one in both table. I would like to put the description in the price 2 column and remove the 3th gridview. Can you guys help me find the solution to let the second table overlap to the next column?

Thanks

```
http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9384/tabelf.jpg

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="False" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" style='table-layout: inherit'>
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
         <%--<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>'></asp:Label>--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("firstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("firstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPriceOne" runat="server" Text='test'></asp:Label>                              
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="False">
                     <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="lastName" SortExpression="lastName">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%"/>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="firstName" HeaderText="Discription" SortExpression="firstName">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>  
                     </Columns>       
                </asp:GridView>                                                              
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPriceTwo" runat="server" Text='test2'></asp:Label>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="False">
                     <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="lastName" SortExpression="lastName">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="firstName" HeaderText="Discription" SortExpression="firstName">
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                        </asp:BoundField>                        
                     </Columns>       
                </asp:GridView> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>        

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Expand" CommandName="Show" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean, that last name column should be hidden and only description column will be visible? And/or you may want the description column should be merged with collapse button? Pls specify more detail.

Comment: Like this: http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/7247/tabel2i.jpg
I will remove the second small gridview (the 3th gridview in the code). The first price and the second price is actually a sum of some prices. The button will show the prices that has been added by each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article which might be useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249155/Rows-and-Columns-Merging-in-ASP-NET-GridView-Contr